# Error inflating TextInputEditText on API 19 device

Tags: java, android, xml

I get this error when I run my app on an API 19 device. Running it on an API 24 works fine.

Here is my code:

***build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.johng.assosfood"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

***fragment_login.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_black" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/emailLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/email"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/email"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/passwordLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/pass"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/pass"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:onClick="validateLogin"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/emailLoginButton"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:onClick="swipeToRegister"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/prompt_notAUser" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="resetPassword"
        android:text="@string/prompt_forgotPassword"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="@string/credits"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

***colors.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimaryLighter">#444444</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF0C2A</color>
    <color name="colorWhite">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorGray">#EEEEEE</color>
</resources>
```

***Styles.xml***

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

***Error log***

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.johng.assosfood, PID: 10900
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at com.example.johng.assosfood.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:14)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2335)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1423)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1754)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1822)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2591)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2378)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2333)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2210)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1239)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1087)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1617)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5379)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:734)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:806)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5379)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5379)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5379)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5379)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5379)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2368)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2246)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1312)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
          at a E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

***LoginFragment.java***

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    public String validation(String email, String password) {
        String msg = "";
        if(email.trim().isEmpty()) {
            msg = "...";
        } else if(password.trim().isEmpty()) {
            msg = "...";
        }
        return msg;
    }
}
```

The annoying part is that it was working yesterday. The only thing I changed is some color attributes to `TextInputEditText` and `TextInputLayout`. I removed `textColorHint` attribute from `TextInputLayout` and I updated the `textColor` I wanted to `TextInputEditText`. Other than these I just changed the background image from the parent activity and the `imageView` on the fragment.

***EDIT***

Seems like if I delete the `drawableRight` and `drawableEnd` the problem is solved.

Comment: Put here your `LoginFragment`! Please

Comment: @AbnerEscócio Added my LoginFragment.java

Comment: It is there but seems like i forgot to copy it here.

Answer (score 0):

**Reduntantia**

> Redundant attribute drawableRight; already defining drawableEnd with targetSdkVersion 27 less

Remove your `drawableRight`

**Deprecation**

> For XML attributes such as paddingLeft and layout_marginLeft, use paddingStart and layout_marginStart. NOTE: If your minSdkVersion is less than 17, you should add both the older left/right attributes as well as the new start/right attributes. On older platforms, where RTL is not supported and the start/right attributes are unknown and therefore ignored, you need the older left/right attributes. There is a separate lint check which catches that type of error.

The same is applied to `drawableRight`, him not is neecessary, use `drawableLeft` instead

Answer (score 0):

**Android Vector Drawables on Pre Lollipop Crash - Solution**

Doing a lot of R&D I got the answer, we need to set the drawable on textView, imageView, imageButton & EditText programmatically.

https://android.jlelse.eu/android-vector-drawables-on-pre-lollipop-crash-solution-45c0c34f0160

```
//region Helper method for PreLollipop TextView & Buttons Vector Images
public static Drawable setVectorForPreLollipop(int resourceId, Context activity) {
    Drawable icon;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        icon = VectorDrawableCompat.create(activity.getResources(), resourceId, activity.getTheme());
    } else {
        icon = activity.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId, activity.getTheme());
    }

    return icon;
}
```